# Where is / what ist the state of fit-content( [ length | percentage] )? (notice the the argument)

Tags: css

MDN tells about this function:

> The fit-content() CSS function clamps a given size to an available
> size according to the formula min(maximum size, max(minimum size,
> argument)).

and later about the state:

> CSS Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing Module Level 3 The definition of
> 'fit-content()'.
> **Working Draft**
>
> CSS Grid Layout The definition of 'fit-content()' in that specification.
> **Candidate Recommendation**

But Firefox and Chrome just say "no".
"Can I use …" does not even know this function.

My explanation is, that until now only the "CSS Grid Layout" context is supported, and "CSS Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing" is not.

But - is this the case? And when will it be available?

Comment: [Can I use... Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width)

Comment: *is this the case?* yes, some function are actually supported in a particular context (example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54491315/8620333) *when will it be available?* no one know, it depends on many factors

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Maybe its just a small error in MDN compatibility table - not distinguishing between "grid" and "general "intrinsic". 1st all browser, 2nd none.